# How to highlight a LongListSelector Item on the UI programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to highlight and manipulate an item of `LongListSelector` on the UI for the user. 
I see [(this)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444) example on code samples but couldn't understand it well.

How can I change background of the inner `StackPanel` which belongs to the `SelectedItem` and add a `TextBlock` into it, programmatically in code behind?

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the sample you linked work with a StackPanel

```cs
private void lls_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  var spList = new List<StackPanel>();
  GetItemsRecursive<StackPanel>(lls, ref spList);

  // Selected. 
  if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems[0] != null) {
    foreach (var sp in spList) {
      if (e.AddedItems[0].Equals(sp.DataContext)) {
        sp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "Hello" });
      }
    }
  }

  // Unselected. 
  if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.RemovedItems[0] != null) {
    foreach (var sp in spList) {
      if (e.RemovedItems[0].Equals(sp.DataContext)) {
        sp.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"];
        sp.Children.RemoveAt(sp.Children.Count - 1);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly since I am new in windows phone development. Here is the code for changing the background of stackpanel and adding textblock to it programmatically.

```
enter code here

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // change the background of stackpanel
        StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
        SolidColorBrush mysolidbrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        mysolidbrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 100,100,10); // RGB color
        st.Background = mysolidbrush;

        // Adding textblock to the stackpanel 
        TextBlock txtblk = new TextBlock();
        st.Children.Add(txtblk);

    }
```

Best,
B